# Append data to file using NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: ios, xcode, file, append, nskeyedarchiver

At some point in my program, I've saved 10 objects to a file at Documents directory, encoding each of them using NSKeyedArchiver.

Now I want to add more objects to my file, but keeping the old ones. Is there a way to do that???

Here is some code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"CurriculaIndex"])
{
    curriculaIndex = [defaults objectForKey:@"CurriculaIndex"]; return YES;
}
else
    curriculaIndex = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSString *path = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"~/Documents/Curricula"] stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSMutableData *dataToSave = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc]initForWritingWithMutableData:dataToSave];

int i=1; //i = curricula index
int j=1; //j = pack index
BOOL parsed = NO;

do {
    NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i.xml", i];
    NSString *thePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSString *encoded = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:thePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSData *data = [encoded dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:data];

    Parser *theParser = [[Parser alloc] initParsing];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:theParser];

    parsed = [xmlParser parse];

    if (parsed)
    {
        [curriculaIndex addObject:curriculum.name];
        [archiver encodeObject:curriculum forKey:curriculum.name];

        if (j == kMaxRegisters) 
        {
            //HERE I WOULD LIKE TO SAVE NEW OBJECTS AT THE END OF THE FILE
            j=0;
        }

        i++; j++;
        NSLog(@"Parsed properly");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Didn't parsed properly");
}
while (parsed);

[archiver finishEncoding];
[dataToSave writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

[defaults setObject:curriculaIndex forKey:@"CurriculaIndex"];

return YES;
```

}

Comment: This is a duplicate of question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663908/how-to-append-data-to-nskeyedarchive

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this (apart from the trivial - and horribly inefficient - approach of re-reading the existing data and writing it out again)?